# Magento home page slider full width

Tags: magento

I installed the slider extension Auguria Slider but somehow it doesn't work like expected.

[image: background image]

How can i make the slider full width?

Comment: Inlcuded the image and re-phrased a bit

Comment: Is the uploaded image big enough?

Comment: yes this is big size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually i have installed  Auguria Slider first we have to know how we download image 
1.first how much  pixel you want image 
2.consider i want width 1200px height 350px
3.then down load 
4.go to magento admin panel select system=>configuration=>right side one option is there that is slider click on
5.it will show slider option
6.how much you want set the value
7.then check your home page magento it will not display do not worry
8. here i have wamp so i go to www=>your folder name=>skin=>frontend=>base=>default=>css=>Auguria=>sliders=>default.css
9.here we have to put some code that is

```css
.auguria-slider-image{
 width:1200px;
 height:600px;
}
```

10.i hope it will work good 
11.you have change pixel range
conclusion
12.how to know how much pixel we want 
13.first go to magento home page cursor put on slider image right click then we will select inspectelement 
14.now we see one box left side corner one arrow mark is there click on then go to slider image it will show how much pixel have 
15.we have to particular image open paint we can change pixel and size 
16.that all
17.i hope it will work fine[`this image last work good[`enter link description here`][1]`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/auguria-slider.html)